# Create JSON from list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this data for a project with a friend:

```
arr = [{'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'Thirdkey 1', 'Value':100},
   {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':130},
   {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 1', 'Value':230},
   {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':300},
   {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 4', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 1', 'Value':111},
   {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':400},
   {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':230}
   ]
```

I tried functions like this:

```
def array_to_dict(arr, classification):
    dct = tree()
    for d in arr:
        dct[d["Key"]]=(d)
    pprint.pprint(dct)

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

def array_to_dict_recursive(arr, classification):
    result = defaultdict(arr)
    for v, k in arr:
        result[k].append(v)
    final_result = [{'type': k, 'items': v} for k, v in result.items()]
    print (str(final_result))

def array_cool(arr):
    #pprint.pprint(arr)
    arr.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('Key'))
    pprint.pprint(arr)
    list1= []
    print("")
    for key, items in itertools.groupby(arr, operator.itemgetter('Key')):
        list1.append(list(items))
    pprint.pprint(list1)
```

And I want it to appear like a JSON file in this way:

```
{
"Key 1": {
    "SecondKey 2": {
        "ThirdKey 2": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 1",
                "Value": 300,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 2",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 2"
            }
        ],
        "ThirdKey 1": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 1",
                "Value": 230,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 2",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SecondKey 1": {
        "ThirdKey 2": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 1",
                "Value": 130,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 1",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 2"
            }
        ],
        "ThirdKey 1": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 1",
                "Value": 100,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 1",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 1"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"Key 2": {
    "SecondKey 4": {
        "ThirdKey 1": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 2",
                "Value": 111,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 4",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SecondKey 2": {
        "ThirdKey 2": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 2",
                "Value": 400,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 2",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SecondKey 1": {
        "ThirdKey 2": [
            {
                "Key": "Key 2",
                "Value": 230,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 1",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I tried sorting, but sorting puts the Key in the second position and mess with the next sorting process, and it's not working.

Comment: What hotel? Objects are not guaranteed ordered, only the arrays are.

Comment: I tried things like this def array_to_dict_recursive(arr, classification):
    result = defaultdict(arr)
    for v, k in arr:
        result[k].append(v)
    final_result = [{'type': k, 'items': v} for k, v in result.items()]
    print (str(final_result))

Comment: Why don't you just `json.dump` it?

Comment: **In your question**, clearly articulate how you want the data to be sorted and show any code that you've tried so far. I don't see the pattern in what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe json.dump will not give me the result I expect, at least not doing it like json.dumps(arr)

Comment: @jonrsharpe also, sorry, Hotel was from another exercise I'm looking

Comment: Please take some time to fix your question: this result doesn't exist in your input: `{
                "Key": "Key 1",
                "Value": 100,
                "SecondKey": "SecondKey 1",
                "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 1"
            }`

Comment: What result do you expect, and why do you expect it, and what do you get instead? Again, *JS objects aren't ordered*, and neither are Python dictionaries.

Comment: @Harvey sorry about the input, it's a mess, now is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a first stab at what you want. It'll get you started and then you can simplify it and make it pretty. Key points:

- `json.dumps()` outputs dictionary keys in the order seen, so an explicitly ordered OrderedDict is probably your only way to get that.
- your result is a different data structure than your input, so you have to build it
- Dictionaries in Python and JSON **do not** have ordered keys. So, the moment you import the result into something else, the order is probably lost.
- This code is really inefficient and will probably perform badly on large data sets.

Your data structure:

- dicts for each `Key`, sorted in order

  - dict for each `SecondKey`, sorted in reverse

    - dict for each `ThirdKey`, sorted in reverse

      - a list containing a dict for each value (no sorting of values) with these sorted keys and values

        - Key1: `Key` value from outer loop
        - Value: value for current item
        - SecondKey: `SecondKey` value from outer loop
        - ThirdKey: `ThirdKey` value from outer loop

.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

arr = [{'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 1', 'Value':100},
    {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':130},
    {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 1', 'Value':230},
    {'Key':'Key 1', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':300},
    {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 4', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 1', 'Value':111},
    {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 2', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':400},
    {'Key':'Key 2', 'SecondKey':'SecondKey 1', 'ThirdKey':'ThirdKey 2', 'Value':230}
    ]

def arr_to_ordereddict():
    d = OrderedDict()
    keys = set(a['Key'] for a in arr)
    #print(sorted(keys))
    for k1 in sorted(keys):
        k1_dict = OrderedDict()
        d[k1] = k1_dict
        arr2 = [a for a in arr if a['Key'] == k1]
        keys2 = set(a['SecondKey'] for a in arr2)
        #print('\t', k1, sorted(keys2, reverse=True))
        for k2 in sorted(keys2, reverse=True):
            k2_dict = OrderedDict()
            k1_dict[k2] = k2_dict
            arr3 = [a for a in arr if a['SecondKey'] == k2]
            keys3 = set(a['ThirdKey'] for a in arr3)
            #print('\t\t', k1, k2, sorted(keys3, reverse=True))
            for k3 in sorted(keys3, reverse=True):
                k3_list = []
                k2_dict[k3] = k3_list
                for item in (a for a in arr3 if a['ThirdKey'] == k3):
                    value_dict = OrderedDict()
                    value_dict['Key'] = k1
                    value_dict['Value'] = item['Value']
                    value_dict['SecondKey'] = k2
                    value_dict['ThirdKey'] = k3
                    k3_list.append(value_dict)
    return d

print(json.dumps(arr_to_ordereddict(), indent=4))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help @Harvey , I will try to simplify, and also I want to make a recursive version, but this is a great start for me :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print json.dumps(arr, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

See the [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) documentation for more information:

> json.dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding="utf-8", default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)

Comment: Hi, this is a sample of the output I got (too big to put here): 
 '[{"Key": "Key 1", "SecondKey": "SecondKey 1", "ThirdKey": "ThirdKey 1", '
 '"Value": 100} 
It's not like a wanted but is a first step

Comment: I forgot to add `indent=4` to the json.dumps call.

Answer (score 1):

Python dicts are unsorted. You have a few options.

Use a tool that applies sorting to a standard dict, example:

```
import json
print json.dumps(thedict, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Use a type that maintains the order of creation of dict entries:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d[KEY] = VALUE
d[KEY][SUBKEY] = VALUE
etc.
```

Or easiest of all, just add them to the array / list in the first place in the order you want them.